# Bonjour IM Client

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bonjour, nsnetservice, ichat

I want to make an iPhone app which communicates with iChat on Mac OS X via Bonjour. I have already known how to create a service using NSNetService, but how can I communicate with iChat? What service type do I need?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Bounjour is not actually used to **communicate** with services. It is only used to *advertise* services.

This means that you can only use Bonjour to `find` the services available on your network.

When you want to talk to those found services, you will have to implement their specific protocol.